# PHP Webservice tutorial

Tags: php, web-services

I know PHP - I have developed websites in PHP - I also know basic apache configuration. 
I have also read up on RESTful webservices. I have learnt how to write a PHP-CLI program which consumes a webservice.

However, I have never developed a webservice.
And am trying to find a good tutorial which explains how to write a simple webservice in PHP & also how to host it on Apache. Most tutorials I have googled seem to use all kinds of frameworks.

I am just trying to write something simple like

call http://mysite/addup.
if you call it with 2 and 4 as 2 parameters, it will add them up and send a 6 back as response.

Is something like this not possible without any additional frameworks. If it is possible, can someone point me to a tutorial.

If not, what's the simplest framework I can use for doing something & a tutorial which explains the same.

I am not looking at SOAP or WSDLs or XML. Just basic stuff.

Comment: If you're don't want to use SOAP, WSDL or even XML, how exactly did you plan to send the parameters to/from the web service, and how did you plan to describe the web service to external applications? Please describe more precisely how would you expect it to work.

Comment: Is http://mysite/ a registered domain?

Comment: You can just pass simple Text as POST or GET - you don't really need XML, right? I will be writing both client & service - so I don't need to explain it to external apps. I am just learning how to write a webservice in PHP - hence trying to keep it simple for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A web service is exactly like a php application, but instead of returning html, you return data for client consumption.

Let's say you have a AddNumbers service which takes two parameters.

AddNumbers.php?num1=25&num2=30

in AddNumbers.php, you check if num1 and num2 are numeric and if they are, you just print the value of num1 + num2.

Then, in the caller of the webservice, you read the returned data and that's it.

However, for interoperability, you might want to format your data with json, xml or whatever, since it might be easier when you have complicated datasets returned from the service. In a real exemple, you might as well use posts instead of gets.

In a real example, in your webservice, you might it a database, fetch some rows and return them in a particular format, insert data in a table or just about anything you can imagine.

If you want to have a restful api, you might want to use mod-rewrite directives in a .htdocs file in the directory on your webserver.

Comment: Returning proper http codes is also nice for WebServices :)

Comment: @ZeissS it is nice, but not required, I just answered the simplest possible thing that can count as a web service since the asker is asking for a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I didn't understand the comment about mod-rewrites. Why would I need mod-rewrites for a RESTful API?

Comment: Often, with RESTful apis, you end up having pretty urls. To get pretty urls you need to use mod-rewrite(an apache module). This module allows you not to have .php extension on the url bar for instance. You could, for example, have an url http://site.com/customers/1/ wich points to http://site.come/customers.php?id=1

Comment: One more question, if I had to use XML for the data exchange, what's the best PHP extension/module to use for this?

Comment: I haven't used PHP in a loooooong time, sorry, but I guess I can't answer that one.